# Android - How to setup child views inside a viewgroup

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can someone help me with my Syntax/Methodology?  I would like to set up a bunch of different views in a viewgroup.  My code fails at the addView method.

Unfortunately, I can’t find jack for examples (which is how I learn) using the ViewGroup class online.

Thanks all.

```
public class TileView extends ViewGroup {
private TestClass mTestClass;
    public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initViews();
    }
    public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initViews();    
    }
    public void initViews() {
        addView(mTestClass);        
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) 
    { 
    }
}

public class TestClass extends View{

public TestClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public TestClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TestClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

}

Comment: @user432209: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the Java stack trace to determine why your "code fails at the addView method".

Comment: OK, here is what I got. There is more, but space is limited.

08-31 14:05:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-31 14:05:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cmllc.testproject/cmllc.testproject.test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class cmllc.testproject.TileView 08-31 14:05:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class cmllc.testproject.TileView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check your own layout xml file. By error message line number 6 is wrong. second problem is you didn't initialize mTestClass object in your view group source code. If you want to get children view, you can use getChildAt(int) method in view group. It is simple example,

```
int count = getChildCount();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
}
```

And, is it full source code? I think you should implement onMeasure and onLayout method in ViewGroup and View instance.

Comment: here is an XML except starting at line 6:  <cmllc.testproject.TileView
  android:id="@+id/game"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tileSize="24"
                />  TileView is a viewgroup...not a view...is this my problem?

Comment: public void addView(View child, int index) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    ...
}
It is part of source of addView(View child) method in ViewGroup. The TestClass instance is not created in your code. And I couldn't understand what you want to make.